# Creating a nested dict with dict.fromkeys()

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's create a nested dictionary with the built-in method `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
dct = dict.fromkeys(["d1", "d2"], {})
dct["d1"]["x"] = 9
print(dct)
# {'d2': {'x': 9}, 'd1': {'x': 9}}
```

Huh? That's strange, I only wanted to change `dct["d1"]`!

This however works:

```
dct = {"d1": {}, "d2": {}}
dct["d1"]["x"] = 9
print(dct)
# {'d2': {}, 'd1': {'x': 9}}
```

What's going on here? Why's `{"d1": {}, "d2": {}}` not equivalent to `dict.fromkeys(["d1", "d2"], {})`? I'm on Python 2.7 if that matters.

Comment: `dict.fromkeys()` does not create copies of the second argument. You are sharing *one single dictionary* between all the keys.